# Deconstructing a postorder traversal and reconstructing a tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have the postorder traversal sequence of `[3 2 1 6 5 4 9 11 10 8 7]` and am trying to get the preorder traversal from the tree built from that sequence. Currently I have the answer:

`7 4 2 1 3 6 5 8 10 9 11` as the preorder traversal and got the root by taking the last value but this answer is incorrect. How do you find the preorder by building the tree? Thanks!

I took the root as the last value from the sequence and then did:

```
       7

     /   \

    4     8

   / \      \

  1   3     10

      \   /    \

      5  9     11

      /

     6
```

but I'm not sure if I built the tree wrong or if I did the preorder traversal part wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A postorder traversal doesn't necessarily give you the actual tree shape.
If you were to assume that it is a binary tree, and each level is filled as much as possible from left to right, then you could have a shape like this for 11 nodes:

```
           x
        /    \
      x        x
     / \      / \
    x   x    x   x
   / \  / \
  x  x  x  x
```

This is the way that I would approach this problem, don't worry about the values at first but the shape.

Once you have a tree that has the right node count and shape that you want/expect, you can just use your post-order traversal to fill in the values:

```
postorder: [3 2 1 6 5 4 9 11 10 8 7]
preorder:  [7 9 1 3 2 4 6 5 8 11 10]

           7
        /    \
      9        8
     / \      / \
    1   4    11  10
   / \  / \
  3  2  6  5
```

If we had given the tree a different shape we could still arrange values to get the same postorder but with th enodes in different spots the preorder would change:

```
postorder: [3 2 1 6 5 4 9 11 10 8 7]
preorder:  [7 10 5 1 3 2 6 11 4 9 8]

           7
        /    \
      10       8
     / \
    5   11
   / \  / \
  1  6  4  9
 / \
3   2
```

Comment: It's probably no coincidence that the given post-order traversal is valid for a binary search tree.

Answer (score -1):

Your tree is incorrect. Assuming that [3 2 1 6 5 4 9 11 10 8 7] is a post-order traversal of a *binary search tree*, then it should look like this:

```
        7
      /   \
     /     \
    4       8
   / \       \
  1   5      10
   \   \    /  \
    2   6  9    11
     \  
      3
```

The pre-order traversal would be [7 4 1 2 3 5 6 8 10 9 11], and the in-order traversal, naturally, would be [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11].